# How to move similar properties to base class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance

In my project, I use 5 different subclasses that depict financial assets: Bond, Fund, Future, Option and Stock. Each of these have a lot in common, so I created the class "BaseAsset" and let all asset classes inherit from that class.

All subclasses have a list of specific Trades (BondTrades, FundTrades etc.).

```
public class Bond : BaseAsset
{
    // Bond-specific properties
    public double FaceValue { get; set; }
    public virtual List<BondTrade> Trades { get; set; }
```

The subclasses also have some properties that all of them implement and that are only slightly different, e.g:

a property that returns the moving average price. This moving average price is calculated based on the specific trades of that class, so it would look like this for the Bond-class:

```
public double movingAveragePrice
{
    get
       {
           foreach(BondTrade trade in this.Trades)
           {
               nominator += (trade.Price.Value * trade.Quantity) / trade.ExchangeRate;
               denominator += trade.Quantity;
           }
           return nominator / denominator;
       }
}
```

And for the Stock-class, it would be pretty much the same, just that it would iterate over the StockTrades. Remark: I also use a BaseTrade-class from which all specific BondTrade, StockTrade etc. inherit.

**How could I move such a property to the BaseAsset?** What's the concept I'm missing? Thank you for any tips or remarks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be to add a list of `BaseTrade` to the `BaseAsset` class and then as long as your `BaseTrade` has `Price`, `Quantity` and `ExchangeRate` you should be able to move the moving average calculation to the `BaseAsset` class.

Comment: Figured out i did not need specific trade classes, so only the "BaseTrade" is left and then I could do as you suggested.. thanks!